# CPU i7 6700k stuck at .80 GHZ

Tags: cpu, windows-installer, lag, intel

Okay I have looked through the internet but unfortunately I am not seeing an answer to my problem so maybe someone can give me some hints here. To start off with what i am currently running.

MSI m5 Motherboard

i7-6700k 4 GHZ CPU

2080 Super GPU

About a month ago, I started noticing my computer starting to lag and stutter alot, almost dropping to 10-40 FPS. When normally my PC can run any games on 4k easily 90-200 FPS depending on the title. So after doing some cleaning of my memory, disc clean up, even going so far as to factory reset my PC to bare bones again.

But alas I could not find the cause to why my computer was stuttering. I honestly began to believe it was my GPU but the moment I pulled up my BIOS, i noticed my BIOS said my CPU frequency was at .80 GHZ and not the usual 4.0 GHZ. My Game Boost and XMP were both off, when I tried turning them on and restarting my PC.

My PC got very angry at me and reset its to default because the overclock was to heavy, which was never the case before as I don't manually do any overclocking myself. After getting back into MSI bios, i hit F6 and reset to Optimized Default settings and the PC was able to turn back on but the CPU was still set to .80 GHZ. I click alot of tabs to also see my Single Core Speed set to 100.00 mhz which i don't know if that is alarming or not.

Here are the troubleshooting steps ive taken.
Factory Reset / turn off turn on / unplug PC / updating intel drivers / updating gpu drivers / remove AIO cpu cooler and reapplying thermal paste (which btw CPU is at a constant 25C).

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/774921223871528990/1137961962974761002/Screenshot_2023-08-06_231259.png

Here is a screen  shot of CPU-Z

Comment: If you google something like "CPU capped at .80 GHz" you get a bunch of similar stories

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/713pz0/comment/dn81wp3/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: which msi m5 motherboard?

Comment: is it same using different OS (Linux for example)?